# How to store multiple xml data into single list using IEnumerable<SyncEntity> in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have to store multiple xml files data into a single list of `IEnumerable<SyncEntity>`, but I don't get exact result as expected. Below is my sample code.

```
public IEnumerable<SyncEntity> GetUpdatedItemsOfType(DateTime? fromDate, string entityName, List<string> fieldsToRetrieve)
    {
        ConnLogger.WriteInfo("Dooors SyncConnector", "Run DOORS DXL for List of Getupdateditems of type ");
        try
        {
            var dxlInput = $"{TmpRootFolder};{entityName};{fromDate.ToString()};{string.Join(",", fieldsToRetrieve)};{fieldsToRetrieve.Count.ToString()}";
            string dxlPath = GetDxl("GetUpdatedItemsOfType.dxl");
            //ActivateAsync(() =>
            //{
            //    DoorsHandle.result = dxlInput;
            //    DoorsHandle.runFile(dxlPath);
            //});
            _doorsHandle.result = dxlInput;
            _doorsHandle.runFile(dxlPath);
            return GetUpdatedItemsOfTypePagination(TmpRootFolder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ConnLogger.WriteException("Doors SyncConnector", ex, "Failed to get list of updateditems of type");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The above `GetUpdatedItemsOfType(DateTime? fromDate, string entityName, List<string> fieldsToRetrieve)` method is where I start one process of doors.

```
private IEnumerable<SyncEntity> GetUpdatedItemsOfTypePagination(string folderPath)
    {
        int currentPage = 1;
        string finishFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "GetUpdateItemsOfType_Finish.xml");
        while (true)
        {
            string xmlFileFullPath = Path.Combine(folderPath, $"GetUpdateItemsOfType{currentPage}.xml");
            bool pageReadCompleted = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) //wait max time of 1,000*0.1 = 100 seconds
            {
                if (!File.Exists(xmlFileFullPath))
                {
                    if (File.Exists(finishFilePath))
                    {
                        yield break;
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
                    continue;
                }

                List<SyncEntity> pageItems = GetUpdatedItemsPage(xmlFileFullPath);
                pageReadCompleted = true;
                foreach (var syncEntity in pageItems)
                {
                    yield return syncEntity;
                }
                break;
            }

            if (!pageReadCompleted)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Timeout reached for GetUpdatedItems method...");
            }

            currentPage++;
        }
    }
```

The above `GetUpdatedItemsOfTypePagination(string folderPath)` method checks the xml files in given folder.

```
 private List<SyncEntity> GetUpdatedItemsPage(string xmlFilePath)
    {
        List<FileAttachment>  fileAttachment=new List<FileAttachment>();
        var xmlData = GenericSerializer.XmlDeSerialize<UpdatedItemsResult>(File.ReadAllText(xmlFilePath));

        return xmlData.Items.Select(field => new SyncEntity
        {
            Name = field.ObjectName,
            Id = field.Id,
            Modified = Convert.ToDateTime(field.LastModifiedOn),
            Fields = field.Attributes.Select(filed => new EntityField
            {
                Name = filed.Name,
                Type = MetadataManager.FromDoorsDataType(filed.Type),
                Value = fileAttachment

            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
        //copy here relevant code from the Execute method
    }
```

The above `GetUpdatedItemsPage(string xmlFilePath)` method is the relevant code to deserialize the xml data.

Comment: So what **is** the result you are expecting?

Comment: Hello, I want to store the multiple xml files data into a single list of type IEnumerable<SyncEntity>